# Plotting a 2D graph in R^3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do a plot e^x into a 3 dimensional space? I'm new to Tex

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={10}{20},
        ]
        \addplot3[
            mesh,
            samples=25,
            domain=-2:2,
        ]
        {e^x};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

would produce a graph of z=e^y

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (make it a MWE).

Comment: I don't understand your question, doesn't the code you have there produce exactly what you want?